# Сохранить все картинки в одном формате JPG или PNG при парсинге Python

Tags: python, парсер, изображения

Есть определенный скрипт на Python который скачивает изоброжения из определенного CSV файла (тоесть я сначало парсю данные каталога товаров на CSV потом из этого CSV скачиваю изоброжения)
Как можно сделать чтобы он скачивал все изображения в один формат JPG или PNG?
или чтобы он преобразовал в один формат все изображения?
Вот сам код:

```
import csv
import shutil
import sys
import time
import os
import logging

# http client configuration
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/63.0.3239.84 Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36'

# logging configuration
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

python_version = sys.version_info.major
logging.info("executed by python %d" % python_version)

# compatability with python 2
if python_version == 3:
    import urllib.parse
    import urllib.request
    urljoin = urllib.parse.urljoin
    urlretrieve = urllib.request.urlretrieve
    quote = urllib.parse.quote

    # configure headers
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', user_agent)]
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
else:
    import urlparse
    import urllib
    urljoin = urlparse.urljoin
    urlretrieve = urllib.urlretrieve
    quote = urllib.quote

    # configure headers
    class AppURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
        version = user_agent
    urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()

def fix_url(url):
    url = quote(url, safe="%/:=&?~#+!$,;'@()*[]")
    return url


def download_csv_row_images(row, dest_dir):
    for key in row:
        start_url = row['web-scraper-start-url']
        id = row['web-scraper-order']

        if key.endswith("-src"):
            image_url = row[key]
            image_url = urljoin(start_url, image_url)

            image_filename = "%s-%s" % (id, key[0:-4])
            download_image(image_url, dest_dir, image_filename)


def download_image(image_url, dest_dir, image_filename):

    image_url = fix_url(image_url)

    try:
        logging.info("downloading image %s" % image_url)
        tmp_file_name, headers = urlretrieve(image_url)
        content_type = headers.get("Content-Type")

        if content_type == 'image/jpeg' or content_type == 'image/jpg':
            ext = 'jpg'
        elif content_type == 'image/png':
            ext = 'png'
        elif content_type == 'image/gif':
            ext = 'gif'
        elif content_type == 'image/webp':
            ext = 'webp'
        else:
            logging.warning("unknown image content type %s" % content_type)
            return

        image_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, image_filename+"."+ext)
        shutil.move(tmp_file_name, image_path)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning("Image download error. %s" % e)

def get_csv_image_dir(csv_filename):

    base = os.path.basename(csv_filename)
    dir = os.path.splitext(base)[0]

    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)

    return dir

def download_csv_file_images(filename):

    logging.info("importing data from %s" % filename)

    dest_dir = get_csv_image_dir(filename)

    #check whether csv file has utf-8 bom char at the beginning
    skip_utf8_seek = 0
    with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile:
        csv_start = csvfile.read(3)
        if csv_start == b'\xef\xbb\xbf':
            skip_utf8_seek = 3


    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf8") as csvfile:

        # remove ut-8 bon sig
        csvfile.seek(skip_utf8_seek)

        csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
            download_csv_row_images(row, dest_dir)

def main(args):

    # filename passde through args
    if len(args) >=2:
        csv_filename = args[1]
        download_csv_file_images(csv_filename)
        logging.info("image download completed")

    else:
        logging.warning("no input file found")

    time.sleep(10)

main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Если на сервере нет картинки в нужном формате, то и скачать ее нельзя. Но можно взять и локально конвертировать. imagemagick - отличная штука, что бы это сделать.

Comment: вы скорее всего меня не поняли, например есть картинка door.png и window.jpg. Мне нужно чтобы после скачивания когда скрипт задает название картинкам чтобы он написал их всех сразу как door.png и window.png например. Если картинку в jpg формате переименовать в png то ничего же не будет впринципе

Comment: я все правильно понял. что бы window.jpg сделать window.png, нужно конвернтуть. Если у Вас линукс, то просто установите ImageMagick и потом в консоли `convert window.jpg window.png` и все будет.

Comment: если там много-много файлов, то в imagemagick есть другая утилита, которая может сделать все `mogrify -format png *.jpg`

Comment: отлично, на виндоусе можно? и как сконвертить только файлы которые находятся в папке img?

Comment: да, можно - скачайте тут https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows , да можно только одну папку - просто зайдите в эту папку и запустите там утилиту.

Comment: спасибо сейчас попробую

Comment: если что, то утилиты, которые там есть, могут и размеры поменять, и яркость/контрастность поправить. Такой себе программерский фотошоп для бедных.

Comment: не разобрался) зашел в папку с изоброженими, открыл CMD и пишу не работает*

Comment: ну наверное оно не может найти бинарник. Ну добавьте в PATH каталог с установленной программой.

Comment: "mogrify" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Хотя добавил в PATH

Comment: может под виндой оно хочет mogrify.exe ? а там в каталоге установки такой вообще есть?

Comment: Все разобрался) оказывается нужно спереди забывал писать magick :D

Comment: Сконвертил все через magick mogrify -format jpg *.png после удалил все png через del *.png

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp_im = PIL.Image.open(tmp_file_name)
image_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, image_filename+".png")
tmp_im.save(image_path, format="png")
os.unlink(tmp_file_name)
```

Comment: Этот код куда поставить?)

Comment: вместо shutil.move